# I don´t know how google drive show my site

Tags: google-drive-api

Sorry my english is very basic. I'm spanish
I created a folder in my google drive and uploaded the site, but i cannot see main page.

Where is my mistake to make it visible?
Thanks for your help

My site is http://gdriv.es/hermaja

Answer (score 1):

When I clicked on index.html.old file, i see your web site. But you can not display it directly on google drive because it is only file storage service. You need at least your own host.

Edit: Also you cannot display your index.php file since your site is not stored in suitable environment for php projects.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Disable file .php and enable file .html, work correctly